# Rails convert model to string separated with comma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

I have a rails object, for example :

```
Book {id:1, name: "name1"}
Book {id:2, name: "name2"}
```

I use the [DataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) and the best ajax data is get the object as an string array, without the columns name.

How can I change the `Book.all` to array of data without columns names

The expected results is like this

Thanks

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect",
      "Edinburgh",
      "5421",
      "2011/04/25",
      "$320,800"
    ],
    [
      "Garrett Winters",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "8422",
      "2011/07/25",
      "$170,750"
    ],
    [
      "Ashton Cox",
      "Junior Technical Author",
      "San Francisco",
      "1562",
      "2009/01/12",
      "$86,000"
    ]
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pluck method like below, then you can get array of values.

```
Book.pluck(:title, :author)
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement the DataTables in Rails.

Use this gem `jquery-datatables-rails` [Click Here](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails)

You have to get the data from the controller as rails object. And populate table your in the view. Finally trigger the DataTable function on that table like this

`

```
$('#yourTable').DataTable({
  // ajax: ...,
  // autoWidth: false,
  // pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  // processing: true,
  // serverSide: true,

  // Optional, if you want full pagination controls.
  // Check dataTables documentation to learn more about available options.
  // http://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType
});
```

No need of conversion into String or JSON